# HTTP Response with two "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" headers

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm implementing client application using http-core which consume HTTP endpoint. While investigate little bit on endpoint response header fields I could find 2 Transfer-Encoding Fields with the value of 'chunked'. After investigating little bit on the HTTP protocol spec I'm able found following section
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6

According to the above resource, This seems to be out of compliance. can someone little bit explain about the Transfer-Encoding header value duplication in the response headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(What's relevant is http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#chunked.encoding)

I agree that multiple "chunked" fields likely are a bug in the server.

Out of curiosity: is the chunked encoding indeed applied multiple times?